# Multiple filters with WebGL PointsLayer on Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I can't find a way to filter the same variable several times dynamically.
For a variable given, let's say `testVar`, I know I can do it this way :

```
const [testStyle] = useState({
    variables: {
      testVar: 'MY_VALUE_SEARCHED',
      testVar2: 'MY_SECOND_VALUE_SEARCHED',
    },
    filter: ['==', ['get', 'featureTest'], ['var', 'test']] && ['==', ['get', 'featureTest'], ['var', 'test2']] ,
```

But what I want is having a search box allowing multiple values, pushing it into `testStyle.variables.testVar` into an array, like this: `testVar: ['MY_VALUE_SEARCHED','MY_SECOND_VALUE_SEARCHED']` but I can't find a way to write my filter function with an array

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'all' expression to achieve that. Put all the filters as parameters to 'all'. Described [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/style/expressions.js).
Your code should be something like;

```
filter: ['all', 
         ['==', ['get', 'featureTest'], ['var', 'test']], 
         ['==', ['get', 'featureTest'], ['var', 'test2']],
        ]
```